# libgobject-2.0 not found on Debian (MXLinux)

Tags: debian

I am trying to install some gtk packages on MX-Linux (Debian) which are packages for the stklos scheme language. I get this error:

Cannot find GTK+ library file "libgobject-2.0"

How can i find and install this libgobject package? Or is it installed by default and the problem is linking issue?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear from your question whether you’re installing binaries or building from source.

If you only need the runtime library, install `libglib2.0-0`, which contains `libgobject-2.0.so.0`.

If you need to build software using `libgobject`, install `libglib2.0-dev`, which will also pull in `libglib2.0-0`; it contains `libgobject-2.0.so` which is what the linker needs, as well as the header files which the compiler needs.